# Увеличение в ширину при максимуме в высоту

Tags: html, javascript

Как можно сделать, чтобы div при достижении максимума в высоту, начинал увеличиваться в ширину?

Comment: А у вас максимум задаётся селектором max-height или как?

Comment: Напримерр.

Comment: А что должно его увеличивать?

Comment: Текст. Нужно чтобы не налезал на другие элементы.

Comment: Вообщем проще ссылку наверное дать http://floberry.ru/about.html

Answer (score 1):

Понял вот:

```
<style>
#id_дива{
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 0px;
height: 40px;
max-height: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: visible;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Честно говоря, не очень понял что вы сделали/попытались. Можете словами объяснить? Я так понял, вы хотели прижать футер так, чтобы он не наезжал на контент. Но вопрос заключался в другом.

Comment: Я сделал так чтобы ширина была ограничена а высота нет!А что вам конкретно надо разве не это ?

Comment: Во-первых, при чём тут футер? Во-вторых перечитайте пожалуйста вопрос. Я хочу, чтобы если в плашке слишком много текста, она переставала увеличиваться в высоту, и начинала увеличиваться в ширину.

Comment: Исправил ответ... это то что вы хотите?